# Zend_View helpers not availble when manually calling $view->render(): how to fix it?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I recently discovered that [view helpers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html) seem to be unavailable when manually calling `$view->render()`.

In this particular case, I've got a config view helper which I can easily call from within my view scripts like so:

```
$this->config()->some->param
```

I am now trying to send a mail and discover that the above does not seem to work when manually calling the render method:

```
/** 
 * Within these view scripts, $this->config() is called, 
 * which results in an empty object
 */
$mail->setBodyText($this->view->render('partials/invite/email/text.phtml'));
$mail->setBodyHtml($this->view->render('partials/invite/email/html.phtml'));
```

***Am I overlooking something? Is this a bug or intended behaviour? Should I take another approach on manually rendering view scripts?***

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can we see a bit more code?

So far I've got this to work with manually rendered views.

```
$view->setHelperPath('/path/to/helper/class');
print $view->render('view.phtml');
```

This here is the class named FooBar.php within /path/to/helper/class

```
<?php
class Zend_View_Helper_FooBar extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract {
    public function fooBar()
    {
        return 'random string this will be the output';
    }
}
```

Within view.pthml

```
print $this->fooBar();
```

Outputs

> random string this will be the output

Comment: Manually supplying the helper path  does it for me as well. This still feels quite buggy to me though. The helper path is registered through my application config file and should already be set.

Comment: If there is already a helper path, then your helper class must be put within that path. Is it there and not working?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the helper path is registered correctly. When rendering views without actually calling $this->view->render() they are being executed fine, which is what confuses. It seems like a manual call to $this->view->render() from within the controller breaks the view helpers.

Comment: Well . I had notice this wired issue , i used to add helpers in config resources.view.helperPath.dagho_view_helper_ = "dagho/view/helper" but  after last update something had changed , i wasn't able to fix that until i add initHelper() function in the config to map it correctly , i agree with Aron its wired

Comment: Ya most likely bugish, can't do to much about it.